# Hive Table from Multiple Avro Files?

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro

I have thousands of Avro files in HDFS directories in the format of yyyy/mm/dd/. In each of these directories there may be 200-400 .avro files with data from that day.

When I create an EXTERNAL table, I think the LOCATION attribute assumes a single file... is there a way to point it at a directory of files and have it read all of them?

Comment: `LOCATION`, if set to a directory, will read all files within the directory.

Comment: Including subdirectories?

Comment: If you want to process subdirectories too you'll want to look at dynamic partitions, assuming you're happy for each day to be a partition, and that there aren't data directories within each day's folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify a partition when you build the table.  Then use an alter table and add parititons as needed like below:

```
create external table mydatabase.NEW_TABLE
partitioned by (date string)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
stored as inputformat    '
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
tblproperties ('avro.schema.literal'='{
"name": "my_record",
"type": "record",
"fields": [
   {"name":"boolean1", "type":"boolean"},
   {"name":"int1", "type":"int"},
   {"name":"long1", "type":"long"},
   {"name":"float1", "type":"float"},
   {"name":"double1", "type":"double"},
   {"name":"string1", "type":"string"},
   {"name": "nullable_int", "type": ["int", "null"]]}');
alter table mydatabase.NEW_TABLE add partition (date='20150304') location '/path/to/somefiles/20150304;
alter table mydatabase.NEW_TABLE add partition (date='20150305') location '/path/to/somefiles/20150305;
alter table mydatabase.NEW_TABLE add partition (date='20150306') location '/path/to/somefiles/20150306;
```

You can add as many parititions as needed.  I recommend you make this table external so that you don't drop the data in the partitions if you make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-QueryandDDLExecution) :

```
hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories
  Default Value: false
  Added In: Hive 0.10.0 with HIVE-3276
```

> Whether the version of Hadoop which is running supports
>   sub-directories for tables/partitions. Many Hive optimizations can be
>   applied **if the Hadoop version supports sub-directories** for
>   tables/partitions. This support was added by MAPREDUCE-1501.

And in turn the Hadoop feature can be toggled with `mapred.input.dir.recursive`.

*Reference:* [that post](http://www.confusedcoders.com/bigdata/hive/hive-customized-data-import-and-query-selected-files-and-folders) (among others)